# Svelte input:bind updates keys of different iterations with the same value

Tags: javascript, svelte

I am looping over keys of object and dynamically updating the values by input from the user,

```
`{#each Object.keys(questions[qn].memberToSubQuestionMap[member].subQuestions) as 
 subQuestion, k (subQuestion)}
<input 
  bind:value{questions[qn].memberToSubQuestionMap[member].subQuestions[subQuestion].answer}
/>}`
```

But the values for all the member keys are updated with same value when user inputs value for one member.

I believe I am using the bind:value the wrong way.

Comment: Can you provide a sample `questions` object? In addition, can you provide a minimum reproducible example? Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you've created an object (probably `memberToSubQuestionMap`) that holds *references* to the `subQuestions` for each user, rather than copies. You'll need to show how you are creating `memberToSubQuestionMap`.